# Hiding/Blocking revised file information in a changelist

Tags: perforce

On P4V windows app,I can select a particular user and a workspace and see the user's list of changes on that particular workspace. When I click a particular changelist from the list of changes, I can see the changed files under the 'Files' tab and then see the actual revisions for a particular file. 
For some reason I cannot see the revised file named in some rare cases and when I click on files tab I see a message saying changes might protected or obliterated. Is it possible to do something to prevent other users from finding out what changes you have made for a particular changelist?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible. A changelist may be marked either public or restricted, and a restricted changelist requires permission to view: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r10.2/manuals/cmdref/describe.html#1040665. It is the 'type' of the changelist that controls this: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r10.2/manuals/cmdref/change.html#1040665

Comment: interesting. what's the rationale for this feature? when would you need to hide something from the rest of the team?

Comment: Myself, I don't use this feature much; I prefer my change descriptions to be public. But differing organizations have differing security needs. What the changelist security feature does is basically to integrate changelist metadata itself into the overall Perforce security architecture, which is based on the protections table and its description of access levels to repository file patterns. Restricted changelists then have those protections applied; if you don't have access to the files that the changelist affected, you don't have access to the changelist itself.